# Empty table in database using Hibernate

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, domparser

I am trying to make a pojo xml file for a pojo class and then create a Hibernate session but the xml file doesn't get updated, the program executes without any error but the table is empty and the data goes inside the previously created table.
What i concluded from this is that my xml file doesn't get updated as soon as create Hibernate session instead it takes the previous data but when the xml is opened new data comes up.
Is there any way of refreshing the xml file so that the new xml data is used in Hibernate?

Comment: I did not get what do you mean by pojo xml?  Are you trying to marshall your instance of pojo to xml and then trying to save it in db?

Comment: It;s like a new xml file is getting created replacing the old one which has the same name but probably the changes do not happen instantly and the project needs to be refreshed.

Comment: Still I did not get that, what xml file you are trying to persist? Are you trying to store xml data in database as clob.

Comment: by pojo xml i meant the mapping xml file for pojo class.I dont know exactly what marshalling is but what i am doing is changing some content of the mapping file.

Comment: I think you are talking about hbm file, right?

Comment: You can not load hbm on fly. Once SessionFactory instance is created using the configuration instance in which you specified your mapping file, session factory instance can't be changed as its immutable. So if you change the mapping then you have to re-instantiate the SessionFactory and get the session object out of that.

Comment: yes pojo.hbm.xml for pojo class. i instantiate the session factory after making the changes to the xml not before that.

Comment: How are you editing your hbm.xml file? I mean after editing you have to save it. Then add that to configuration instance, then create session factory instance and finally get session object to do db operations.

Comment: using domparser and saving it to the same location of the previous file.

Comment: Make sure you are flushing and closing the stream which writes to hbm.xml file. Moreover, after writing to file try to open that file in your favourite editor and see if changes are there. After making sure that changes are there then only use this in your configuration instance.

Comment: closing is not in there in domparser but adding the filepath to the configuration instance worked.Thanks a lot!!